# Downlights in two rooms come on by itself, after electrical failures

Tags: electrical

Good day,

We sometimes have electrical failures at home, which results in the downlights of two rooms turning on by itself when the power is restored. I looked at the switches, but all seems in order and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are these 100% simple switches - just on/off? Or do they have any of: dimmer, WiFi, remote control, timer, motion sensor, "smart" in any way?

Comment: Quite often people would turn on light switches to tell when power was restored.  Is it possible this is what happens?

Comment: Good day, thank you for your responses. Its dimmer lights switches. The lights is switch off as we dont use them often. When the power is restored, the two rooms with down lights just comes on by itself...don't know why. Its definitely switch off before we have power failures.

Comment: Do dimmers have a separate on/off function(need to switch on/off separately from dimmer function)?  Could be a defect or feature of the dimmer switch, would think about changing the switch/s.

Comment: What make/model are these dimmers, and do they have a "hard" mechanical on/off switch, or...?

Comment: The dimmers don't have a seperate on/off switch. Both rooms dimmer just have one switch each. The one rooms switch have been replaced 2 years ago, the other switch in the 2nd room have last been replaces about 6 years ago. Maybe I should replace both or consider getting an electrician out to assist.